# Review Helpfulness Datasets

Tags: data-request

My team is looking for a user review dataset which we can compare to one of these [Amazon datasets](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)

The dataset needs to include text reviews and a review helpfulness rating.

I know this is a long shot, but if anyone knows of a dataset we could use then that would be great!

Comment: "to one of these amazon datasets" - what are these amazon datasets? where have you looked for this data already?

Comment: Added the link - thanks! We've had a look at movie and book review datasets, mainly found through Kaggle, UCI ML Repo and Stanford's SNAP datasets. We found a few Rotten Tomatoes datasets online but the reviews didn't contain a review helpfulness rating which is what we're looking for. We're hoping to do something similar to this: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4781139